# Understanding Python coalescing operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, variable-assignment

What does the following line of code mean in Python?

```
id = result and result[1] or False
```

Note: This question combines both operators "and" and "or". However, other questions asked in "Stackoverflow" take into account having only one of those operators in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is to avoid `IndexError` being raised if the sequence `result` (e.g. list, tuple) contains fewer than 1 item. But, if this is the intention, it is flawed because Python sequences are 0-based and `result[1]` accesses the *second* item in the sequence. Checking that the list is not empty does not guarantee that a second item exists. Probably the intention is to check that there is at least *one* item in the sequence and to get the *first* item in the sequence, not the second.

And, due to short-circuiting, the `or False` is actually superfluous anyway.

It is a shorthand way of doing this `if` statement:

```
if result:
    id = result[1]
else:
    id = False
```

but as I said it seems flawed. This would be better:

```
try:
    id = result[1]
except IndexError:
    id = False
```

or perform a length check:

```
if len(result) > 1:
    id = result[1]
else:
    id = False
```

or:

```
id = result[1] if len(result) > 1 else False
```

or to continue the horrible inline method in the question:

```
id = (len(result) > 1) and result[1]
```

Which just highlights that code should not be written in the manner shown the question: it is not immediately clear what the intention and outcome of the code is, and some thought is required to understand it. An if statement is much more readable so it should be used.

Comment: Also worth noting perhaps that it's not **exactly** the same as your `if` statements if `result[1] = 0` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an equivalent Python code for that line:

```
if result:
    id = result[1]
else:
    id = False
```

It basically means:

> If `result` evaluates to `True`, assign `id` the second element of `result` list, else assign `id` the boolean value `False`

Answer (score 0):

That code assign `result[1]` item (second item of list or second letter rom string) to `id` variable if it exists otherwise `False` would be assigned to id.

**Note** In case if result list containing only 1 item that code would fail with `IndexError`.